# Are there any gems which can enforce Ruby code conventions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style

Are there any gems which can enforce ruby/rails coding conventions as mentioned by the guides below.

```
https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide
https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide
```

Comment: i use a ruby formatter for sublime text 2.

Comment: how do you format, can you elaborate?

Comment: https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My two favorite gems for handling code cleanliness are Reek (https://github.com/troessner/reek) and Cane (https://github.com/square/cane). I don't know that they go down to the nitty-gritty of indentation and spacing, but they detect a lot of Ruby coding conventions that tend to otherwise get overlooked.

In terms of spacing / indentation / casing and so forth, I'd either look for an editor configuration (e.g., download a Ruby package for TextMate / Sublime Text / EMACS / what have you), or look into the BeautifyRuby gem (https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby).

Comment: Cane explicitly avoids indentation and spacing checks. I've never seen an algorithm that is both accurate and fast, and I don't presume to be able to write one. (It does pick up trailing whitespace and line-length though.)

Answer (score 8):

[RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) is a static code analyzer based on the Ruby Style Guide, by the same author.

The [Rails Best Practices](https://github.com/railsbp/rails_best_practices) gem can detect certain problems in Rails projects.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question, which wasn't about favorite analyzers, but about tools checking `bbatsov/ruby-style-guide` and `bbatsov/rails-style-guide`.